# Google app script (java script) and crypto currency data

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, cryptocurrency

I am just learning google app script and java script so please be gentle :-) 
I have this google app script (java script) that scraps data from 
the website coinmarketcap and it is working very well but I want to make some modifications to it and I need some help.

```
function pullJSON() 
{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var response =        UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/");
    var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); 
    var dataSet = dataAll;
    var rows = [], data;

    Logger.log(dataSet); 

    for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) 
    {
        data = dataSet[i];
        rows.push([data.id,data.price_usd]); //your prefered data variable 
    }

    dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, rows.length, 2);
    dataRange.setValues(rows);
}
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v5nNgtowYR23dmmpBZA9aOJyX_H7DfEh/view

I want to make the following modifications to it:

1) Move the preferred data variable (price_usd) outside the for loop. Something like this (I have tried the code and it does not work):

```
var select = price_usd; //your prefered data variable 
for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) 
{
    data = dataSet[i];
    rows.push([data.id,data.select]); 
}
```

I think it is more intuitive for the user to change the value of the variable outside the loop instead of inside the loop.

2) In cell(1,1) of the sheet I want the user's selection of the data he or she wants. A new row need to be created for that. If the user put in: `var select = price_usd`  then cell(1, 1) should read: Price in USD

If the user put in: `var select = total_supply` then cell(1,1) should read: 
Total Supply

etc etc

3) This might be the hard part. Each time I run the script I want a new column to be created and the first row of that column should contain the current time stamp and from the second row and downwards the new data.

A loop has to be created to check that data is entered at the right row for each crypto currency. The order of the crypto currencies can change when the data is return from a new call to coinmarketcap 
so just assuming the order is the same as in the older column or simply sorting the column alphabetically
will not work.

4) A loop that remove any crypto currency (the complete row) that have any missing observations. The data from the coinmarketcap url contains the 100 coins/ tokens with the biggest market cap so a coin / token 
can be ranked for example 99 one day (included in data call) and the next day ranked 101 (not included in data call) which will lead to missing data observations. The simplest solution to this is to just remove 
these crypto currencies.

Any help that accomplishes my set out goals for the code would be most appreciated.

PS. I have an old Google app script (the script works but it is slow) that does something similar but for stockmarket data but I am uncertain of how good it is and if anything can be learnt from it:

It assumes that you have a Google sheet open with sheets called: Blad1 and Panel  and cell(1,1) in sheet Blad1 contains

```
=IMPORTDATA("http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-industry.aspx?exchange=NASDAQ&render=download")
```

The old stock market price google app scripts is:

```
function PanelCreation_Stock() 
{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Blad1"); 
    var dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Panel"); 
    var curDat = new Date();
    var day1 = curDat.getDay();
    if(day1 == 0 || day1 == 1)
    {
        return;
    }
    var lCol = dstSheet.getLastColumn();
    var srcdate = dstSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, lCol).getValues();

    for(var k=1;k<=srcdate[0].length-1;k++)
    {    
        if(Utilities.formatDate(srcdate[0][k],"GMT", "dd-MMM-yy") == Utilities.formatDate(curDat,"GMT", "dd-MMM-yy"))
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    var snRows = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
    var dnRows = dstSheet.getLastRow();  

    var srcStock = sourceSheet.getRange("A2:A" + snRows).getValues();
    var srcLastSale = sourceSheet.getRange("C2:C" + snRows).getValues();

    var dstStock = dstSheet.getRange("A2:A" + dnRows).getValues();
    var dstLastSale = dstSheet.getRange("Z2:Z" + dnRows).getValues();

    for(var j=0;j<dnRows-1;j++)
    {
        dstLastSale[j][0]="n/a";
    }
    var flag = "true";
    var foundStock;
    for(var i=0;i<snRows-1;i++) //snRows
    {  
        var sStockVal = srcStock[i][0];

        //var foundStock = ArrayLib.indexOf(dstStock,0, sStockVal);

        flag = "false";
        for(var j = 0; j < dnRows-1; j++)
        {
            if(dstStock[j][0].toString().toUpperCase() == srcStock[i][0].toString().toUpperCase())
            {
                flag = "true";
                foundStock = j;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag=="true")
        {
            dstLastSale[foundStock][0] = srcLastSale[i][0];            
        }
        else
        {
            var dnRows1 = dstSheet.getLastRow()+1;
            dstSheet.getRange("A" + dnRows1).setValue(srcStock[i][0]);
            dstSheet.getRange(dnRows1,lCol+1,1,1).setValue(srcLastSale[i][0]);
            for(var k=2; k<=lCol; k++)
            {
                if(dstSheet.getRange(dnRows1, k).getValue()=="")
                {
                    dstSheet.getRange(dnRows1, k).setValue("n/a");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    dstSheet.getRange(1,lCol+1).setValue(curDat);  
    dstSheet.getRange(2, lCol+1, dstLastSale.length, 1).setValues(dstLastSale);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It will be better if you split your question into 4 separate questions. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for inspiration

Comment: yeah, the post is overwhelming, please follow the suggestion by Alex Yu, ask one question at a time

Comment: +1 Alex Yu and YakovL. Regarding "Move the preferred data variable", you don't (but should) explain the motivation. Let me speculate that you are trying to let the user decide which fields to see in an output table. Your code doesn't work because the data field is `data.price_usd`, not "data.select". Try (untested) `var select = data.price_usd;`, and then push `select`, not `data.select`.

Comment: If the price isn't the same for every element, then you can't move it outside of the loop.  You can try: `var price = dataSet[0].price_usd; //price from first element  
for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) 
{
    data = dataSet[i];
    rows.push([data.id,price);
}`